# How to add configure.xml to a Jenkins Job Programmertically?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm creating a new project as below. And in addition to that, I want to add a `configure.xml` file that I've saved in my disk.

```
FreeStyleProject proj = 
                   Hudson.getInstance().createProject(FreeStyleProject.class, "JobName");
```